# Ordinary linear system with dimension 3 and two independent eigenvectors

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the following system of ODEs
$$
\overline{X'}=
\begin{bmatrix}
    5 & 2 & 0 \\
    0 & 5 & 0 \\
    0 & 3 & 5
\end{bmatrix} \overline X
$$
The characteristic polynomial has 3 identical real roots $\lambda_{1,2,3} = 5$
I have found two eigen vectors for $\lambda = 5$ which are,
\begin{bmatrix}
    1  \\
    0  \\
    0 
\end{bmatrix}  and
\begin{bmatrix}
    0  \\
    0  \\
    1 
\end{bmatrix}
I know how to get two independent solutions. How do I get tge third?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Denote the system's matrix with $A$. You have found that $\text{Ker}(A-\lambda I)=\langle(1,0,0),(0,0,1)\rangle$. This has dimension $2$, which is not equal to the eigenvalue's, which is $3$.

Now you have to continue finding kernels of powers of $A-\lambda I$. In this case, $(A-\lambda I)^2=0_{3\times 3}$, so $\text{Ker}[(A-\lambda I)^2]=\mathbb{R}^3$, and you may take your third vector as $(0,1,0)$, which is linearly independent from the first two.